# Can someone identify these Lego sets? White with large transparent blue walls

Tags: set-identification

I am looking for some help to identify the sets to which these pieces belong. Have been searching for some time without luck…
Any experts that can please assist?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First one is from [Arctic Mobile Exploration Base (60195)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60195-1) since there is only one more set that has more than 3 pieces of [Trans-Light Blue Rock Panel 2 x 4 x 6](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47847&colorID=15&in=A) and that set doesn't have included white pieces.

[image]

The rest is from [Defense of Crait (75202)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75202-1), which was easy to identify since there are just five sets (by the time of this answer) using [Light Bluish Gray Brick, Round Corner 3 x 3 x 2 Dome Top](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=88293&colorID=86&in=A).

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is amazing! Thanks Alex! Really cool forum!!!

Comment: @Henning If the answer has helped you, please mark it as accepted. You can learn how to do that in the [help].